Form rules and validation not working, only HTML is working
This is my first time using JQuery, and im really struggling with it, my form validation/rules arent working at all. And im just curious as to why? if anyone could help.
I'm currently trying to make the forms first name and last name need a minimum of 2 letters and have email validation. but i dont know why none of it is appearing? heres my js and form
                <form id="contactForm">
                    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name..." required>
                
                    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name..." required>
                
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Yourname@email.com..." required>
                
                    <label for="subject">Query</label>
                    <textarea name="subject" id="subject" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
                
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script> 
    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#contactForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    firstname: "required",
                    lastname: "required",

                    email: { 
                        required: true, 
                        email: true 
                    },
                    subject: { 
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 10 
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                    lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                    email: {
                        required: "Please enter your email address",
                        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
                    },
                    subject: {
                        required: "Please enter your query",
                        minlength: "Your query must be at least 10 characters long"
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
                
            });
        });
    </script>


You're loading jquery.validate.js, but you don't seem to be loading jquery.js. Is that a copying error or a problem in your real code? Do you get any errors in the console?

thats a copying error on my part, however in the console I do have an error message of "jquery(...) validate is not a function", I'm not totally sure what I'm doing wrong

There's no version 1.19.5 on that CDN.

The correct URL is https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.min.js

Why not use the build-in form validation? I have two event listeners. One for the invalid event that is fired if an element is not valid. And one for the input event that fires when something is inputted into one of the form fields.


document.forms.contactForm.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

document.forms.contactForm.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if(e.target.validity.valid){
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

form>label {
  grid-column: 1;
}

form>input,
form>textarea {
  grid-column: 2;
  justify-self: start;
}

form>.feedback {
  grid-column: 2;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.invalid + .feedback {
  visibility: visible;
}
<form id="contactForm">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name..."
    minlength="2" required>
  <div class="feedback">Please enter your firstname</div>
  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name..."
    minlength="2" required>
  <div class="feedback">Please enter your lastname</div>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email"
    placeholder="Yourname@email.com..." required>
  <div class="feedback">Please enter a valid email address</div>
  <label for="subject">Query</label>
  <textarea name="subject" id="subject" minlength="10" required></textarea>
  <div class="feedback">Your query must be at least 10 characters long</div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



